# Android Automotive Instrument Cluster Emulator

Tags: android-source, android-automotive

I built an image of Automotive, and I run with emulator. The emulator starts an Instrument Cluster automatically. Where is code of logic to start the cluster in AOSP?

By the way, can I use the same way to create another display in Android emulator? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can support with first part of question.
You can start from here:

`packages/apps/Car/Cluster/src/android/car/cluster/MainClusterActivity.java`

and any file with `Fragment` prefix in the same folder to check particular view.